# Pass multiple parameters to #selector

Tags: swift, methods

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath:indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
    cell.myButton.addTarget(self, action: "myClick:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
}
```

func myClick(sender: UIButton) {

}
Now, i want to pass one another parameter to sender : UIButton ,
so how can i pass?

Answer (score 0):

The only parameter you can send, is sender, in your case is UIButton.